# inserting Session data in data base in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

Halu guys
I have created the following session table in my database

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
    );
```

and here is code in my controller

```
$data=array(
'username'=>$this->input->post('username'),
'is_logged_in'=> true
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

here is config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = 'TRUE';
$config['sess_use_database'] = 'TRUE';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = 'TRUE';
```

but when I logged in, the data is not stored in data base what is wrong with the  code? thank you for your support!!!!

Comment: It might be your session settings in `config.php`. Please edit your question and include those settings. Have you followed the [directions here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver)?

Comment: Are you not able to retrieve session data?

Comment: @DFriend 10q I have edited the question now and I'm not able to  insert username and other session data in ci_sessions table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line in config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

to this

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

I hope this help you...